# Are Brillouin's papers translated into English?

Tags: physics, reference-request, translations

I mean the Brillouin in the WKB method. I want to read his original paper. But it is in French. Is it translated into English? It should be.

Comment: I can't help you, but it sure is ironic that a user named poisson is averse to papers written in French.

Comment: Normally they do not translate French papers into English. These languages share 60% vocabulary, and even more in mathematics.

Comment: Léon Brillouin has his name on many works. In [this wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9on_Brillouin#Books) I see 5 of 19 books translated to English. Was there a particular work you wanted? The question seems terribly general. What particular "original paper" are you talking about?

Comment: The paper on the WKB method in quantum mechanics

Comment: Why not include bibliographic details or a link to the paper for the convenience of others? Do you mean this: https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/jpa-00205271/document ?

Comment: If that link I gave is to the paper you want then I am dubious that the paper ever got translated out of French. It really is easy French. Much of the scientific terminology is very close to English, as Alexandre Eremenko suggested is generally the case. Learn a couple of prepositions and you should be able to read this.